# Hangfire is not running all my scheduled jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I'm using **Hangfire 1.5.3** in a ASP.NET MVC project with many scheduled jobs, more than 1.7k. A time ago I detected that some jobs are not running when they suppose to run. If I run any of this scheduled jobs manually they work perfectly. Also, I noticed that my list of succeed jobs is near 130 millions and I'm getting timeouts trying to access this list through the Hangfire dashboard and recently I'm getting timeouts trying to access the Hangfire dashboard. Is there a safe way to clear my Hangfire's tables without removing my scheduled jobs? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally updated Hangfire to version 1.6.15, the first time that my scheduled jobs ran, one job did not run and I have to run it manually but after that every job has ran fine